# Android (Kotlin): Risks of running Room query on main thread ( < 1400 data values )

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-room

I'm wondering what the possible drawbacks are to running my queries on the main thread. At the moment I am loading data from a database using Room and am using this data to generate graphs for the user.

I have already tried putting my queries into separate threads using a runnable, but I am having issues with the application attempting to use data which has not yet been loaded due to the separate thread not finishing it's operation in time. I understand that I could implement some sort of listener or notification, but even then, the user will have to wait an undetermined amount of time before they may view the content because the data for the graphs that they are wanting to view never loads before the button that loads them is clicked.

I have done quite a bit of research and found that it is unadvisable to put the queries on the main thread because it could possibly hang up the thread for a long time and give a poor user experience. So, assuming that I will never exceed 1400 data members, should I worry about this? Are there any caveats that I have not been informed of?

**Edit:** I am testing the device on a Samsung SM-J106B which is running Android 6.0.1 and I have not noticed any impact on performance even when loading the max of 1400 data members.

Comment: are you aware of google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library?

Comment: 1400 is a lot for UI thread. Use paging lib.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am testing it right now on a Samsung SM-J106B running Android 6.0.1, API 23 and using dummy data. I am not experiencing any noticeable impact on performance.

Comment: Use Rx or LiveData to observer the results of your queries. It's very easy.

Comment: I don't really see why would you want to perform anything apart from drawing (assigning values to TextViews and etc.) and handling events (clicks, adapter's events, etc.) on UI thread. What's the point? These days there is plenty of solutions to effortlessly implement asynchronous calls, I strongly recommend you reading this: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do

Answer (score 0):

DB queries could take long enough that they would cause the UI to skip frames causing a bad visual experience or worse trigger an app not responding exception.

Comment: Will this happen with larger data sets or are there other conditions which may trigger this?

Comment: An old device with app running on low quality SD card can do lots of things. It's not wise to relate on modern powerful devices being able to swallow up some load on UI thread, whilst old ones will break with ANR